# Uipath RPA Automation Screen Scraping Errors

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have an image which is a scanned copy of a page, in .tiff format. As per my research, UiPath doesn’t support tiff format -  so i converted it manually to jpg, using it as an input. As it is a image, I am using screen scrapping along with Google OCR - the quality is not as expected, but they are at an acceptable level. Now, the issues that I am facing are as mentioned below.

1. While working with screen scraping, I have done the complete process of scrapping on one system. When I move it to another system, I am getting below error. [image: Error Image]
2. Is there a better way to get the text from the image?

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting below error

Make sure your selectors are resilient by using wildcards. The most likely cause for your error is that UiPath looks for a window with the exact title `your-file-name.tif` (you redacted that part). This will always fail when you open another image with a different name.

This selector looks for an IrfanView application with the precise title:

```
<wnd app='i_view32.exe' cls='IrfanView' title='UK1.tif - IrfanView (Zoom: 618 x 874)' />
```

By introducing wildcards, you can just look for any tif file opened in IrfanView:

```
<wnd app='i_view32.exe' cls='IrfanView' title='*.tif*' />
```

> Is there a better way to get the text from the image?

Instead of opening the image in a viewer, you can directly load it into a variable of type `System.Drawing.Image`. Note that this supports most TIFF files, as well - so, there is no need for conversion. Then you could use the `Google Cloud OCR` activity to perform OCR, storing the words and OCR text in two dedicated variables. Check out the [help](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/google-cloud-ocr) for more details.

[image: Google OCR in UiPath]

Comment: hi Wolfgang Randi, Thanks for your reply, the selector issue I am able to solve, but the issue is like when working with screen scrapping if I am spying the fields they are working correctly on the system where I have spyed , but when i transfer the .xaml to other system its showing the error as show above. The second question is that when working with tiff there are multiple images and how to navigate through those. The third question while working with Google OCR i dont want the full text from the image i just want certain fields from the image, how can i get this

Comment: Ad 1: can you use Studio on the second system? If yes, open your workflow, and update the selector by using the "Indicate on Screen" button. Then, compare the results - this should give you a good indication of what was going on. Ad 2 and 3: UiPah isn't really an ideal solution for OCR plus data extraction (you might want to check out Kofax, Ephesoft, or other vendors). Here's what you could do, however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998081/uipath-rpa-scrape-data-from-images/50048360#50048360